# Show Component inside a Collapsible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, antd

Hello I'm trying to show a Form Component inside an 'antd' Collapsible when the user clicks on the form icon the Form Component should appear inside the Collapsible below the text that's already there

I'm using the antd library for the Collapsible

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { Collapse, Icon } from 'antd';
import Form from './Form';

const { Panel } = Collapse;

const text = `
  A dog is a type of domesticated animal.
  Known for its loyalty and faithfulness,
  it can be found as a welcome guest in many households across the world.
`;

const genExtra = () => (
  <Icon
    type="form"
    onClick={event => {
      // If you don't want click extra trigger collapse, you can prevent this:
      event.stopPropagation();

      console.log('You have click on edit form');
    }}
  />
);

const customPanelStyle = {
  background: '#f7f7f7',
  borderRadius: 4,
  marginBottom: 24,
  border: 0,
  overflow: 'hidden',
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Collapse
    bordered={false}
    defaultActiveKey={['1']}
    expandIcon={({ isActive }) => <Icon type="caret-right" rotate={isActive ? 90 : 0} />}
  >
    <Panel 
      header="This is panel header 1" 
      key="1" style={customPanelStyle}
      extra={genExtra()}
    >
      <p>{text}</p>
    </Panel>
  </Collapse>,
  document.getElementById('container'),
);
```

this is the Form Component:

```
import React from 'react';

const Form = () => {
  return(
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div className="group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" />
      </div>
      <hr/>
      <div className="group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

--
I just want the Form Component to appear inside the collapsible when the user clicks on the little icon in the header I'll leave a link to the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pkffgm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your `Collapsible` to another class based component, where you can have state to show / hide your `Form` component,

In newly constructed class based component you need to maintain state like,

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={
      showForm: false
    }
}
```

Then in render you can show your `Form` like this,

```
<Panel 
      header="This is panel header 1" 
      key="1" style={customPanelStyle}
      extra={this.genExtra()}
>
      <p>{text}</p>
      {this.state.showForm && <Form />}
</Panel>
```

And finally on click of form edit icon you need to change state of `showForm` like,

```
genExtra = () => (
  <Icon
    type="form"
    onClick={event => {
      // If you don't want click extra trigger collapse, you can prevent this:
      event.stopPropagation();
      this.setState({showForm: true})
      console.log('You have click on edit form');
    }}
  />
);
```

**Note:** In the `Form` component you are getting warning for your `lable`,

```
<label htmlFor="name">Name</label> //instead of `for` attribute in react we have `htmlFor` attribute.
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-absy6e)